# jQuery - How to use each() in click event jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Please see my html code:

```
<form action="#" class="check_opt" id="ckPrice">
    <p><input class="niceCheck" type="checkbox" name="" value="0-49">3 millions - 10 millions (21)</p>
    <p><input class="niceCheck" type="checkbox" name="" value="50-99"> >10 millions - 15 millions (7)</p>
    <p><input class="niceCheck" type="checkbox" name="" value="100">15 millions and above (15)</p>
</form>
```

And jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#ckPrice :checkbox').click(function() { 
            var price = 'abc'; 
            $(".niceCheck").each(function() { 
                if ($(".niceCheck").is(":checked")) { 
                    price += $(".niceCheck").value(); 
                } 
            }); 
        alert(price); 
        }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

The alert function in bottom jQuery code only returns 'abc'. How should I do this?

Comment: This is jQuery code:   <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#ckPrice :checkbox').click(function() {

   var price = 'abc';
   
   $(".niceCheck").each(function() {
    if ($(".niceCheck").is(":checked")) {
     price += $(".niceCheck").value();
    }
   });
   
   alert(price);
  });
 });
  </script>

Comment: `input` elements shouldn't be wrapped in `p` elements. Use `label` instead. Equally your `+=` is going to give an odd result with the values "0-49", "50-99" and "100" - selecting all 3 will give you "0-4950-99100".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank for your great answer. Hi, I want to select values are checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
if ($(".niceCheck").is(":checked")) {
    price += $(".niceCheck").value();
}
```

to:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    price += $(this).val();
}
```

Your `.each()` call is looping through the elements you want and you need to refer to them via `$(this)`. Also jQuery uses `.val()` not `.value()`. Of course, since you have unusual values your end result will be a string with something like "abc50-99100"

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6ssmn/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are checking against the first one

```
 $(".niceCheck").each(function() { 
    var check = $(this);
    if (check.is(":checked")) { 
        price += check.val(); 
    } 
 });
 alert(price);
```

Comment: I should do $(this).val(); instead $(".niceCheck").value();, it will doesn't work. Morever, I want to use click event and then use each() method to get all value are checked. Thank for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was about to correct this but had a little problem which needed urgent response.

Comment: No problem! I'm very happy when you fixed your answer and now it works. Thank so much! hi.

Answer (score 1):

Your each function should use `this`

```
$(".niceCheck").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        price += this.value;
    } 
});
```